# How capture with regex optional values where order doesn't matter?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match an entire string and capture with ruby the value of `text`, `when` and `image` on a string the a string that has any of the following cases:

```
@bot post text:a when:b image:c
@bot post text:a
@bot post when:b image:c text:a
@bot post when:b text:a
```

I've manged to write a regex that works with the first case:

```
/(?:@bot) post text:(?<text>.*) when:(?<when>.*) image:(?<image>.*)/
```

How can I change it so that each argument is optional and can be provided in any order?

You can the current regex in http://rubular.com/r/YG1pnCzdUC

Comment: You could match all `\w+:\w+` and then iterate over the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ "@bot post text:a when:b image:c".scan(/(text|when|image):(\S+)/).to_h
#⇒ {
#  "image" => "c",
#   "text" => "a",
#   "when" => "b"
# }
```

To match the whole string and then capture, just match the whole string and then capture:

```
▶ matcher = /(?:@bot) post ((text|when|image):(.+?)(?:\z|\s+))+/
▶ scanner = /(text|when|image):(\S+)/
▶ "@bot post text:a when:b image:c"[matcher].scan(scanner).to_h
```

---

Or, in one match:

```
▶ "@bot post text:a when:b image:c".match(
▷   /(?:@bot) post ((text:(?<text>\S*)|when:(?<when>\S*)|image:(?<image>\S*))\s*)+/)
#⇒ #<MatchData "@bot post text:a when:b image:c" text:"a" when:"b" image:"c">
```

http://rubular.com/r/YG1pnCzdUC

Comment: Thanks. Though this doesn't solve my issue as I have to match the entire string and then catpure. This is due to the library I use: https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-bot#generic-routing

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You might use the regexp I provided as you want. If you need to use it to match—just do it.